# IntelliJ won't save SVN authentication information

Tags: svn, ide, intellij-idea, credentials

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate version 11.1.4 on OS X.

Every time the application starts, or I update from SVN, I am prompted for my SVN credentials. Even if I click "save credentials" they are not stored.

[This ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55531) describes a workaround where one changes SVN to store plaintext passwords. This does not resolve my issue.

How can I get IntelliJ to store my SVN credentials?

Comment: Does it help if you make a new clean installation from the `.dmg` and do not modify any files in the `.app` folder?

Comment: A reinstall is not entirely off the table, but I'd rather not lose all of my other IDE settings to fix this one issue.

Comment: Settings will be preserved, they are not stored in the `.app` directory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This problem can occur if there are any modifications in the `/Applications/<app>.app` directory. It's new since Mac OS 10.8 as the application is now signed and OS checks the signature when running.

If the signature doesn't match because of some change in the files (like after installing patch update or adjusting options in `Info.plist`), application access to the system keystore is blocked (as well as some other features). When it happens, passwords cannot be saved.

To fix the problem delete the application directory and extract it again from the `.dmg`. Don't worry about the settings, they are [stored elsewhere](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) and will be preserved after this procedure.

Comment: Thank you @CrazyCoder. Maybe its an old Windows habit, but I did not expect the reinstall to be painless. My problem has been solved. I think I might ask a followup question at the Apple StackExchange site, I wonder if it is possible to refresh the Keychain signatures without a reinstall.