# Subversion in Intellij keeps asking for authentication

Tags: svn, authentication, intellij-idea

I am trying to checkout a project from subversion but for some reason it doesn't let me.

At first when I put the URL, it gives me options such as whether I want to authenticate via password,ssh agent or ssh key etc.
I choose the authentication with password option. At this stage the login is successful as I can browse my repository.

However, when I go to checkout a project from my repository, it asks for authentication again; I input the password but it keeps asking for the password again

The following window keeps popping.
[image]

I have tried the following solution without success:

- Cleared the authentication cache from the intellij subversion settings.
- Uninstalled and installed intellij again
- Found online that the following line might help if added to idea.exe.vmoptions

  `-Dsvnkit.http.methods=Basic,Digest,NTLM`

but this didn't work either.

Any advice?

Comment: Can I assume you are selecting the "Save Credentials" checkbox? (sorry for the obvious question, but don't want to assume anything)

Comment: What platform are you one? What version of IntelliJ? This answer may help if you are on Mac OS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585631/intellij-wont-save-svn-authentication-information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I checkout the project, I have to set a few options such as directory location, subversion version. 
I checked the 1.7 version instead of the 1.8 one and it worked. So I guess it was something to do with using the wrong version of subversion.
This  was on windows 7, intellij 13.1.4

Hope it helps

Comment: Same here though I had to go from 1.7 to 1.6 on a Mac, Intellij 13.1.5. On a Windows same repository is checked out in 1.7 format.

Answer (score 36):

In IntelliJ, the problem can be solved using the following steps for the following versions.

IntelliJ 2018.1

- Go to `Settings -> Version Control -> Subversion`
- Check the option `Enable interactive mode`.

IntelliJ 14

- Go to `Settings -> Version Control -> Subversion`
- Uncheck the option `Use command line client`.

Comment: This is broken as of `2018.1`. I had success with going to `Settings -> Version Control -> Subversion`, and checking `Enable interactive mode`.

Comment: @the_storyteller I did that and restarted IntelliJ, no luck :/

Comment: @the_storyteller please post it as answer so I can upvote ;>

Comment: @Line, I edited the above answer. If the functionality changes and the answer is edited, it'll be correct and still have the most upvotes so people'll be able to find it easily.

Comment: @the_storyteller I don't see the edit. Besides, I kind of don't agree with you - your answer would be just different. Additionaly, from the edit you would have 2 points, if you post an answer like I ask you to, only from my upvote you would have 10 ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can go to the svn console and perform any svn command like:

```
svn list https://www.repo.rr.com/svn/main/team/gaurav
```

Then svn promt password and ask if you want to save password. If you save password, Intellij will see the password too.

Comment: If you are using more than one username for some reason or have recently changed your password, then you might have to delete this file. This path is relevant for Macs-
<user.home.directory>/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/<some-hashed-file-name>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it turned out that (at least on Windows), it was using the "svn" command-line client, which happened to be version 1.7 (and I think my server is on 1.8).  So I solved the problem by going into settings and unticking the "Use command-line client" option.  Then it worked fine, presumably using its internal svn client.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix it by specifying the **exact** path to the 'svn' executable,
in the settings -> version control -> subversion window. Apparently the auto detection functionality of Jet brains-products behaves wired sometimes.

Under Linux you can easily find that path by running `which svn` in a Terminal.