# Intellij SVN keeps asking for path to certificate when there is none

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

A slightly different version of this
[Subversion in Intellij keeps asking for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620605/subversion-in-intellij-keeps-asking-for-authentication)

I enter my credentials just fine. Once I enter the correct credentials it takes me to a popup that asks for my path to certificate, and certificate passphrase.
[image]

This didn't used to happen until I changed my SVN password. Prior to this, simply enter in my SVN credentials would work fine without issue. Hitting cancel on that gives me an SVN:E175013 error, and hitting OK closes then reopens the same box.

The same issue does not happen in Eclipse. Simply providing the userid and pwd will allow me to access SVN, this is only happening in intellij.

So I cleared the SVN settings for my PC in the %APPDATA% path, as well as my Intellij svn's directory (.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system) I cleaned vcs/vcsCache and vcs-users in that folder.

My Intellij info

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3
Build #IU-171.4424.56
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1

I'm using svn 1.9.5.1210.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately resolved the issue by uninstalling Intellij and all cache, settings everything. Then reinstall. Was able to fetch from SVN henceforth.

I wasn't able to test Dimitri's note before I did the reinstallation, but it sounds like it could be it.

The wrong password can be saved by IDE in a storage according to Settings - Appearance & Behavior - System - Passwords. Check the storage, probably set IDE to not remember passwords and restart. – Dmitriy Smirnov

Answer (score 6):

No need to re-install intellij to fix this issues, at least this worked in my case.

Goto Webstrom -> Preferences -> Version Controle -> Subversion

and uncheck "Use Command line client" if it's already checked.

click "Clean Auth Cache"

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Seems similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150404

Try clearing SVN credential cache using **Settings - Version control - SUbverion - General | Clear auth cache** button

Comment: I tried that, then I found out it was clearing the %APPDATA% svn cache, so I just did both. Still not working.

Comment: The wrong password can be saved by IDE in a storage according to Settings - Appearance & Behavior - System - Passwords. Check the storage, probably set IDE to not remember passwords and restart.

Comment: I think this might have been it, but I ultimately uninstalled and reinstalled Intellij which resolved the issue as I had to purge all cache data. Which I imagine also deleted the saved pwd that you're refering to. I'll leave your comments in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues today with SVN. It was a permissions element on the repo within SVN, where I had stated that the permissions were to be inherited for the branch, instead of setting them directly.

As soon as I set the permission directly on the SVN server, the issue went away.