# IntelIJ IDEA every time ask me about svn password

Tags: java, intellij-idea, svn

IntelIJ IDEA 2022

When I start I save svn  password like this:

[image]

But after restart IDEA it AGAIN ask me about the password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subversion in Intellij keeps asking for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620605/subversion-in-intellij-keeps-asking-for-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have checked "enable interactive mode"  under Preferences | Version Control | Subversion

Comment: I remove folder .subversion. In  IDEA input svn password, save pass, restart IDEA. And now never ask me about svn password